# Cannot change page in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i've a problem with my datatable...

The problem is: I can't change the page after inizialization....

The workflow that i desire is:

- A user select a radiobutton in page 3
- i save the id of this radio and the curent page
- i destroy datatable
- when user re-enter in datatable (re-creating datatable) I wish that user would go directly to the page 2

This is my code:

```
    $('.js_select').click(function (e) {
        var oTable = $("#id").DataTable({
        ......
        });


         $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {

            oTable.fnPageChange(2);

         });

    });
```

P.S. 2 is an example to test function :)

But i get this error in consolle:

```
Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnPageChange is not a function
```

What can i do?

Thanks

Comment: can show your code to js fiddle so that we can help you fast....

Comment: close the brcket of oTable after $document backet

Comment: it's closed :-)

Comment: `fnPageChange` will only work on a oldschool dataTable jQuery instance. So use `dataTable()` or `$("#id").dataTable().fnPageChange()` but `stateSave` is a h*** of a lot easier :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`stateSave`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave), it will do exactly what you need atomatically :

```
var oTable = $("#id").DataTable({
  stateSave : true,
  ...
});
```

Now each time the table is instantiated it will restore the settings from last session, i.e pagination, sorting, search-phrase ...

Comment: The above solution is the simplest and to the point. It saves its settings in the localstorage like Datatables_YourTableId on the page. Whenever you are coming after log out. it will restore the setting of the table. but in some case after log in with different users same settings are not required so better to clear localstorage if you are in c# like that localstorage.clear(); in document.ready() area.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var currentPaging = 1;

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
  } );

  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    oTable.fnPageChange(2);
  });

  $('#example').on( 'page.dt', function () { 
    var info = $('#example').DataTable().page.info();
    var page = info.page + 1;

    alert('Current paging : '+page);

    currentPaging = info.page + 1;
  });

  $('#memorizePaging').on("click", function (e) {

    alert("I'm on the page : "+currentPaging);

  });

} );
```

I did a fiddle to show you fnPageChange works : https://jsfiddle.net/z4zgp9az/5/

Comment: now i'm going to try, but i don't need this fn on initcomplete because i have to start at page 2 only if a global var is not empty..

Comment: Then surround the fnPageChange with a if condition. What is your global variable ?

Comment: i tried you fn...the result is: nav bar is setted correctly to 3 (because dt start numbering pages at 0) but the rendered page is the first as usually, not the third...

Comment: Same first error John:   Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnPageChange is not a function

Comment: Look at my fiddle update, when you keypress on the document you go to the page 3 (You should click on the datatables to see it in jsfiddle because the focus isn't set on the result)

Comment: now it works!!! i remove dt inizialization from var otable =   :)  John do you know how can i memorize my current page on $('#id').on( 'page.dt', function () {  ?

Comment: Look at my fiddle update. I added the current page when you change page. If you want to memorize it you can initialize a variable a the top of your javascript file and initialize it in the `page.dt` event.

Comment: You can click on the button `What is my current page` at the top to check the current page

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "DataTable" should begins from small character "dataTable"
It should helps:

```
 $('.js_select').click(function (e) {
    var oTable = $("#id").DataTable({
    ......
```

change to:

```
 $('.js_select').click(function (e) {
    var oTable = $("#id").dataTable({
    ......
```